# xPath Java - Change the value of an item close

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am a beginner in xPath and my XML I have items that are close (empty)

```
<Info>  
    <Personne>
         <field name="Name" type="String">
             <value type="String"> TOTO </value>
        </field>>
        <field name="CountryCode" type="String">
             <empty />
        </field>
    </Personne>
    <Personne>
        <field name="Name" type="String">
             <value type="String"> TOTO </value>
        </field>>
        <field name="CountryCode" type="String">
            <empty />
        </field>
    </Personne> 

ETC.......

</Info>
```

I can not seem to read the empty items

```
expression = "/Personne/field[@name='Name']/* | 
                  /Personne/field[@name='CountryCode']/*";    

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression)
                      .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);    

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
    System.out.print(nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
```

I find just Name's values in my table

And I would give to "empty" a value String like for example "null" in my table of node

- My XML file is very big ! (1M lines ...) and aproximately 750 000 empty
- JDom takes enormously time...

Thanks !

Comment: The dynamics of the problem indicate towards to a SAX Parser instead, where you can decide to take an action upon hitting an element `empty`. Using DOM might be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes are selected but `getNodeValue()` returns `""` for empty elements.

Since you used `System.out.print` you don't see any output for the empty elements.

Simply check if the value is empty and then convert it to a `null`:

```
String value = nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
if ("".equals(value))
     value = null;
System.out.print(value);
```

Comment: There is no way to display even a null value when it encounters an empty value ?

Comment: I tried but I threw an exception : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Jason then do something against the NPE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Your XML sample contains 'Personne' nodes but your XPath expression contains 'Personnes' ... is that a misspelling? It may be worth your while to print the node name as well as its value:

System.out.print(nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeName()+":"+nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

Comment: Thank you for the note , it is a writing error post because it is an example that I 'm writing

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to access a child node if the element can be empty but rather read out the text content with e.g.

```
expression = "/Personne/field[@name='Name']/* | 
                  /Personne/field[@name='CountryCode']/*";    

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression)
                      .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);    

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
    String value = nodes.item(i).getTextContent();
    System.out.print(value.equals("") ? "null" : value);
}
```